# Set verbose_name value as field value

Tags: python, django

I want to automate the verbose_name value to be the same value as the "name" field value of the object in database table.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = '"ADM"."PERSON"'
        # Just an example:
        verbose_name = (super).name.getValue()
```

I wonder if this makes sense or a query will be needed and some "on_update" event

Comment: "verbose name" is meant to replace the display of the model itself in the admin, in your case `"People"`. It is not a record-dependent value.

Comment: @Brian that's exactly what I want, the display name on the admin to be unique for each object

Comment: What no, it makes no sense, verbose_name is the name for the Model, not for the object. You can't call the class "Peter" just because you have a Person instance whose name is Peter.

Comment: @Brian Well, in the admin you can see the list of objects in a model, but they all have the same name, I wanted them to be unique instead. But I guess that's not what verbose_name is for...

Comment: Your `Person` in the example clearly gets its `name` from the database, so unless you modified the `PersonAdmin` (or something) for that field somewhere else, you should definitely be seeing individual `name`s for each `Person`.

Comment: @Brian Sorry, I meant to say they all have the same display name(aka verbose_name) in the admin screen, in this case , "Object Person" by default

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to set a [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#str) method for your model.

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Person(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```